# pyspark / python 3.6 (TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable) list / tuples

Tags: python, lambda, pyspark, rdd

I have this code in pyspark / python:

n --> is a number of itens of new list

```
n = 2

new tuple ( x, y, z )
```

Where:

```
x --> index

y --> list [where variable n is a number of itens of list]

z --> value of front value of list
```

I'm doing this code:

```
RDD_Dados = RDD_one.map(lambda x: (x[0], 
                                  [list(x[i][1]) for i in range(n)],
                                  x[i+1][1])
                        )
```

Content of RDD_one is:

```
(0, [(0, '5'), (1, '1'), (2, '2'), (3, '4'), (4, '4'), (5, '3.5'), (6, '-2'), (7, '1'), (8, '2'), (9, '0')])
(1, [(1, '1'), (2, '2'), (3, '4'), (4, '4'), (5, '3.5'), (6, '-2'), (7, '1'), (8, '2'), (9, '0')])
(2, [(2, '2'), (3, '4'), (4, '4'), (5, '3.5'), (6, '-2'), (7, '1'), (8, '2'), (9, '0')])
(3, [(3, '4'), (4, '4'), (5, '3.5'), (6, '-2'), (7, '1'), (8, '2'), (9, '0')])
(4, [(4, '4'), (5, '3.5'), (6, '-2'), (7, '1'), (8, '2'), (9, '0')])
(5, [(5, '3.5'), (6, '-2'), (7, '1'), (8, '2'), (9, '0')])
(6, [(6, '-2'), (7, '1'), (8, '2'), (9, '0')])
(7, [(7, '1'), (8, '2'), (9, '0')])
(8, [(8, '2'), (9, '0')])
(9, [(9, '0')])
```

I would like to get each secound item of each duple and make a new list like this:

```
(0, ['5','1'], '2')
(1, ['1','2'], '4')
(2, ['2','4'], '4')
(3, ['4','4'], '3.5')
(4, ['4','3.5'], '-2')
(5, ['3.5','-2'], '1')
(6, ['-2','1'], '2')
(7, ['1','2'], '0')
```

but doesn't work.

I have been reciving this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-3532f6a9c36a> in <module>(
59 RDD_Dados = RDD_one.map(lambda x: (x[0],[list(x[i][1]) for i in range(n)],x[i+1][1]))

  File "C:\Spark\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 229, in main
File "C:\Spark\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 224, in process
File "C:\Spark\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\serializers.py", line 372, in dump_stream
vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
File "<ipython-input-12-3532f6a9c36a>", line 59, in <lambda>
File "<ipython-input-12-3532f6a9c36a>", line 59, in <listcomp>
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Is there any reason you want to have both characters of integers and integers?  (e.g., `(0, '5')`).  Just curious.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
RDD_Dados = RDD_one.map(lambda x: (x[0], 
                                  [list(x[i][1]) for i in range(n)],
                                  x[i+1][1]))
```

for

```
RDD_Dados = RDD_one.map(lambda x: (x[0], 
                                  [x[i][1] for i in range(1,n+1)],
                                  x[n][1]))
```

`range` starts at `0`, so you are doing `x[0][1]` in the first iteration. However, `x[0]` is an integer, hence your problem. Also, you don't need to wrap `x[i][1]` with `list` otherwise you would get e.g. `(0, [ ['5'], ['1'] ], '2')` instead of `(0, ['5','1'], '2')`

---

Edit:

For a more generalized and flexible approach, you may create a custom function where you can further extend logic.
For example:

```
def my_logic(x):
   ret = [x[0], []]
   for i in range(1, n):
       try:
           ret[1].append(x[1][i][1])
       except IndexError:
           ret[1].append(0)
           break
   if len(x[1]) > n:
       ret.append(x[1][n][1])
   else:
       ret.append(0)
   return ret
```

And then just do

```
RDD_Dados = RDD_one.map(my_logic)
```

Comment: I did it. And I catch this error:

    TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list

Comment: if you variable `n` an integer? Notice, I edited the code, the last piece should be `n`

Comment: Yeap.
I tried do this:

RDD_Dados = RDD_one.map(lambda x: (x[0], 
                                  [x[i][1] for i in range(1,int(n)+1)],
                                  x[int(n)+1][1]))

and show me this error:

TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list

Comment: Try `RDD_one.map(lambda x: (x[0], [x[1][i][1] for i in range(1,int(n)+1)], x[int(n)+1][1]))`

Comment: Ir got out of range because your last element in RDD has only one element and you are trying to iterate twice (i.e. `n=2`)

Comment: How do you want to  treat these cases @PabloLuizLeon ?

Comment: Then I just want to go through every existing list in RDD this FOR using range...  there other way to do this?

Comment: fill this case with zero. like this:

( 9, [0], 0)

Comment: @PabloLuizLeon like this?

Comment: In that case I'd like to fill in zeros. As no example: -> (9, [0], 0) Index = 9
list = [0]
value = 0

Comment: In this cases, I think that I need to do a filter in my RDD first, to eliminate this cases ? @RafaelC

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this issue doing it:

First, I Make a RDD using filter to remove unecessary data, acording the number of parameter N.

```
RDDFilter = DadosAgrupadosPorChaveOrdenados.filter(lambda x: n < len(x[1]))
```

After it, I do another RDD mounting data, like I needed:

```
DadosFinal = RDDFilter.map(lambda x: (x[0], 
                              [x[1][i][1] for i in range(0,int(n))], 
                              x[1][int(n)][1]))
```

Thank you so much, for any help.